# Can't inset a new item to array when afterInsert called WIX Corvid

Tags: javascript, velo

I wrote the following function on the backend => dataa.js file

[image: backend => java.js file.]

```
      let recived_msg_users = [] ; 

export function chat_afterInsert(item, context) {


     let user_date = []
          var now = new Date();
          var nowTimeStamp = now.getTime();

           let hookContext = context;  // see below
           user_date.push(item.userIdb)
           user_date.push(item._createdDate.valueOf())

        recived_msg_users.push(user_date)

        console.log("new msg added",recived_msg_users)


        }
```

Now I go to preview mode and I expected to see on the console, every time I insert a new table row +1 items of recived_msg_users array, but I got constantly a length of 1 every time I Insert item into the table, WHY?

It could be caused by this error?

```
 Hook afterInsert for collection chat result ignored! Expected hook result to resolve to an object with an '_id' property, but got [Undefined]
```

Anyway, why I got this error? what is wrong?

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causes that error is ending the function with `return item` to the hook function. Your current function isn't returning anything.

However, the bigger issue is that you cannot update the recived_msg_users array in the hook, because the items won't persist outside of the hook. It's not storing the information anywhere, because everything in the data.js hook file runs on demand as a serverless function, so the variables don't exist *until* one of the hooks is called.

If you want to persist the information, you can store this information in another DB, or the same one.